# frontend cloud run app can not access my backend cloud run app due a MixedContent problem

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, google-cloud-run, mixed-content

I have two cloud services up and running.

- frontend (URL: https://frontend-abc-ez.a.run.app/)
- backend (URL: http://backend-abc-ez.a.run.app/)

Frontend is calling the backend through a nuxt.js server middleware proxy to dodge the CORS problematics.

The call is coming through - I can see that in the backend log files. However the response is not really coming back through because of CORS. I see this error in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://frontend-abc-ez.a.run.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://backend-abc-ez.a.run.app/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What I find weird is that I configured the backend url with `https` but it is enforced as `http` - at least that is what the error is telling me. Also I see a `/login` path segment in the unsecure URL. Why is that? I never explicitly defined that endpoint. Is it the security layer proxy of the run service itself?

Anyway - I need to get through this properly and am having a hard time to understand the source of the problem.

Comment: Why don't you allow for a proper and secure CORS setup? No need to dodge it if you can have access to it IMO. Also, can you please share your Nuxt config file please? Do you have some env variables?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason as I rechecked the applications today in the morning everything went fine. I have really no idea why it is working now. I did not change a thing - I waited for the answers here before I'd continue.

Very weird. But the solution so far seems to be waiting. Maybe Cloud Run had some troubles.